# Checking if a Word table's cell is empty - Empty cell containing a "marker"

Tags: vba, ms-word

This Word file has a giant table with 2 columns. I have to make a statement like:

```
If theCellIsEmpty, then
    Fill it
End if
```

The thing is that when I get the content of the cell through:

```
FirstCellText = ActiveDocument.Tables(Tbl).Cell(Rw, 1).Range.Text
```

It doesn't get the `""` I'm expecting, but it contains a sort of dot, so the text read is never empty.

Here is the dot I'd like to test for: [image: Here is the dot I'd like to test]

Moreover, I have no idea what this dot can be or where it came from. I tried to find it in the characters table without success.

Could someone explain me how to test the presence of this "end of line character" or the emptiness of the row? I don't want to check if the cell only has 1 character as if this character is something put there with a purpose, I don't want to delete it.

Also, every single line has this dot at the end...

What is it? How can I use/avoid it?

Comment: In Word, go to `File | Options` then select the `Display` panel. You should have a section called `Always show these formatting marks on the screen`. (That's where it is in Office 2016, other versions may differ.) Make sure all the check marks in that section are clear, then try your code again. If that fixes it, your solution is to programatically turn those options off before running your code. You'd probably want to store the current options and reset them when your code is finished so you don't upset your users by resetting their preferences every time they use your code.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. It didn't work. By the way, you have this small icon with a sort of "|P" that does the same. These are just markings to represent things otherwise invisible to us (spaces, lines jump, sections breaks etc)

Comment: The other option (instead of changing settings) would be to use the Immediate Pane `Ctrl-G` and type `?ASC(FirstCellText)` to find out what the ASCII code for that character is. Then your test becomes `If FirstCellText = vbNullString or ASC(FirstCellText) = <someASCIIvalue> Then FillIt`

Comment: I understand what they're for, I was guiding you to test whether disabling the display of those meta-characters would also disable returning them in your code.

Comment: Have you tested to see if, when you're getting that "dot" character if `FirstCellText = vbNullString` is `True`? If it's true then that's all you need to test for, no matter what the debugger is showing you

Comment: Hello, I tried the "Asc(FirstCellText)" witch gives a n°13 corresponding to the "carriage return". I'll try to test for it even if I'm not sure how to (google might have the answer).
Trying the "vbNullString" was my first idea as "it's empty", but nope, it doesn't work, there is something in the cell... :'(

Comment: The character you are finding is the end of cell marker.  It cannot be deleted.  For an empty cell you need to test if the number of characters is  1.  <range>.characters.count=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need is something like:

```
Dim Cll As Cell
For Each Cll In ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  With Cll.Range
    'if all it has is the end-of-cell marker, it's empty, so fill it
    If Len(.Text) = 2 Then .Text = "Filler Text"
  End With
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your help, I might have a simple solution thanks to Freeman, mostly :-)

I took the ascii number of the character to check what it is (through asc(xxxx) function) and it happens to be a "carriage return" having the ascii number "13"

Therefore, so I just need check if the content of the cell gives the ascii number 13 and it's done. (the "asc(xxxxxx)" gives the ascii number of only the first character of the text chain :) )

Of course, if the cell starts with a carriage return and there is text after, it won't be nice, so checking also if the text contained in the cell is only 2 char  long will be a nice thing (this "carriage return" is apparently 2 char long... strange...) :)

```
If  Asc(FirstCellText) = 13 and len(FirstCellText) = 2 Then
```

Comment: Word table cells end with chr(13) chr(7). If those are the first two characters in the cell, the cell is empty.